# How to install fly cli in windows 10

Tags: concourse

I'm a newbie to concourse and it needs fly cli. I'm on windows 10 pro 64 bit.

Upon opening the fly.exe I downloaded from https://concourse-ci.org/ nothing happens.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: It is a command line tool, you have to invoke it from the command prompt.

Comment: that means, each folder that will use the fly.exe should have fly.exe inside its folder?

Comment: No. You can download the zip file from concourse and extract it. Then update PATH with the location of fly command. You should be able to use the command from any folder. You have to create targets for each team that you may have in concourse

Comment: thanks for the help! it's working now. cheers!

Comment: Okay, let me update it as the answer!

Comment: sure! will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fly` is a command line tool.

Follow these steps to install it in Windows,

1. Download the zip file for windows from [concourse-ci.org](https://concourse-ci.org/)
2. Extract the zip file to a folder (say, `C:\concourse\`). The executable `fly.exe` is now available under `C:\concourse\fly.exe`
3. Update the `PATH` environment variable with this new directory `C:\concourse\`
4. Open command prompt and run `fly.exe`.